# uGet and Chrome/Chromium download integration

Tags: chromium, downloads, uget

How can I integrate uGet and Chromium so that any downloads that would usually happen within Chromium will occur in uGet instead?

Please provide a link to any extensions required.

Comment: Extension available [Here](http://ugetdm.com/blog/6-news/31-uget-extension-for-chromechromium-is-now-available).

Answer (score 4):

first get this extension , its no no longer available in chrome store , I have no Idea why the developer removed it, I've uploaded it here http://www.mediafire.com/?3m4xl539pz3sz7i drop it on chromium then just do this http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2011/03/new-chrome-extension-brings-support-for.html

works seamlessly for me. do you use the aria2c plugin ? if so , do you get an "aria2c version error" ?

Answer (score 3):

**Update** My extension is now adopted by the uGet team and made the official extension. Please follow this wiki to integrate uGet with your favourite browser

https://github.com/ugetdm/uget-integrator/wiki/Installation

---

I have developed a new extension to integrate uGet with Google Chrome, Chromium, Vivaldi and Opera. This extension can automatically interrupt your downloads and send them to uGet. Also you can right click on links and select 'Download with uGet'.

See uGet Chrome Integration in action: [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3WGGdmyvJ0)

To install the extension follow these steps:

1: Add the PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper`

2: Download the package list: `sudo apt update`

3: Install uget-chrome-wrapper: `sudo apt install uget-chrome-wrapper`

4: Install [uGet Integration Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/uget-integration/efjgjleilhflffpbnkaofpmdnajdpepi) extension to your browser from the chrome web store. Opera users get the extension here: [uGet Integration Opera Extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/uget-integration/)

5: Restart the browser

For more details, visit to the GitHub site: [uGet Chrome Wrapper](https://github.com/slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper)

Comment: It doesn't work on Ubuntu. I always get "Cannot connect to u-get-integrator, even though it's installed as per instructions on the github repo/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old question but...we are currently in development for a custom integration extension of Chrome -> uGet. (Opera integration is also in development)

Comment: we have finished the extension for chrome but unfortunately Google broke it in the latest version of Chrome...we are working on a new version that will compensate for Google's breakage. - here is the link for the blog post of the original extension, http://ugetdm.com/blog/6-news/31-uget-extension-for-chromechromium-is-now-available

Answer (score 1):

The uGet team now provides an [extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/urlget/files/uGet-Chrome-Extension/1.x/uGetIntegration-1.0.1.crx/download) to integrate with chrome/chromium. Download the [extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/urlget/files/uGet-Chrome-Extension/1.x/uGetIntegration-1.0.1.crx/download) and drag and drop it on your browser's extension manager to install it. Your browser's right click context menu will now have an entry `uGet Link` that you can use to download files.

Answer (score 0):

if http://ubuntudaily.net/2012/04/how-to-fix-aria2-getversion-result-error-in-uget doesn't work

try these arguments, they worked for me

-x 4 -k 1M --enable-rpc --rpc-listen-all=true --rpc-allow-origin-all

where x is the number of connections (change it to whatever you want, maximum for aria2c is 16 I believe) 
k is the split size

but as of chrome 20.0.1132.47 beta downloading links with uget doesnt seem to work, all I get is %u in the address field.

In download assistant options replacing  ***uget-gtk %u***   with   ***uget-gtk  "$URL"***
works. 
cheers.